# Is $f_n=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$ uniformly convergent on $D=(-\infty,+\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Is $f_n$ uniformly convergent on $D=(-\infty,+\infty)$ ?
$$
f_n=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}
$$

**My solution**
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=|x|\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_D|f_n-f|= \sup_D||x|-|x||=0\ \ \ \forall x\in D
\end{aligned}
$$

So $f_n$ converges uniformly on $D$.

Am I correct?

Comment: First of all, try to detail why your statement would be true, more precisely why could you say that $\lim \sup |f_n-f| = \lim \sup ||x|-|x||$ ?

Comment: I forgot to remove the limit symbol. Now it should be clear.

Comment: You are interchanging the supremum and the limit. That is not a valid argument.

Comment: You correctly state that $f_n(x) \to \lvert x \rvert$, but this is pointwise covergence. To prove unifom convergence, you need an additional argument.

Comment: @Bonrey Yes but it was still false. In fact, you were using uniform convergence to prove uniform convergence. The answer of Kavi is the good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not valid since you cannot take the supremum after taking the limit.

$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac {(x^{2}+\frac 1n ) -x^{2}} {\sqrt {x^{2}+\frac 1n } +|x|} \leq \frac {1/n} {\frac 1 {\sqrt n}}=\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ and this prove uniform convergence.